# Automatically increment number every nth row without Drag&Down until specific number is reached

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a sequence where number increments every nth row without Drag&Drop, because there are so many rows! The sequence starts from 0, and increments 1 every nth row until it reaches 11. Is there a way to do it?

I tried =INT((ROW(A3)-3)/$Z$3)+0 where it increments every nth number given in Z3. But I should Drag&Down it every time as I have many to do it. Is there a way to do it automatically untill it reaches 11?

Comment: Try: `=INT(SEQUENCE(11*3,,0,1/Z3))`

Comment: Please include an example

Answer (score 0):

Just found a MUCH nicer technique provided by `Mayukh Bhattacharya` in another post on the site ( [Find the corresponding row ID and column ID of top 3 values in a matrix in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871321/find-the-corresponding-row-id-and-column-id-of-top-3-values-in-a-matrix-in-excel) ) which he solves a rather different problem with, but is much more precise than the first method I gave (below):

```
=TOCOL( IFNA(  SEQUENCE(11,1,0,1),  SEQUENCE(,Z3)  ))
```

It removes the creating a list of elements with fractional components altogether, and so all the difficulties that come with wrangling them into the nice list one desires. It could still be generalized for all the relevant variables (Z3 for the "how many times" variable is shown). Very straightforward, and as his use for a very different problem shows, extensible to more than one kind of need.

Originally:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(  SEQUENCE( (11 + (1-0) )*Z3, , 0, 1/Z3),  0)
```

`SEQUENCE` will then start with 0 (3rd parameter) and rise by 1/Z3 each new element to the set. The 1 for the 2nd parameter will keep it to a single column. The 1st parameter will calculate how many rows to do. I've generalized that so you can replace the 0 in it with whatever desired starting number you have, which would also mean changing the 3rd parameter as well. If you ever need this again. If not, just collapse the first parameter to be 12. If you would use it again, you might want to generalize further to have the highest number reached and the beginning value in cells as well as the "how many of" value that is in Z3.

This gives a sequence like "1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6..." but you want integers. Simply rounding down is the easiest way to get them, and actually is the mechanism that made the whole thing possible. I like to use `ROUNDDOWN` because it gives absolute control over how Excel approaches the rounding, while `INT` can act differently from planned on when negative numbers are in the mix. (NOT in this case... in this one it would act as desired. But using `ROUNDDOWN` means never having to concern yourself with it.) I actually prefer `QUOTIENT` for most integer-izing as it gives the integer that most uses desire (though it does NOT help in this use... it will give an extra first value and one too few of the last value), or `TRUNC` which is sort of the gold standard for getting the value you expected with no funny Excel-isms. But I thought `ROUNDDOWN` instructive here because it does the job in an "explained by looking at it" way that the others don't. `TRUNC` has just as much absolute control over things though.

The other part that is key is the adding of a fractional part to each element to get the next so one has a list of, say, 13 elements starting with a 1, and so on for each integer mark along the way, to feed into the truncation function you use.

Comment: Hi, I first thought that it worked nice, but I noticed something. The number of rows with the same value differs, e.g. I set to increment every 28 rows from 0. The number of rows with 0 is 28, with 1 is 26, with 2 is 27, whereas I need that all of them should be 28.