# Find the corresponding row ID and column ID of top 3 values in a matrix in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, excel-formula

I have the following matrix.

[image]

The output I want to receive is.

[image]

I have implemented `LARGE()` function to find the top 3 values. I have tried implementing `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` functions in one formula to receive the above output but was unsuccessful. How can we get the above output in excel?

Comment: Just to be sure, values are not unique and 2 same values with different coordinates are possible?

Comment: I think your result table has a typo for `73` the `RowID` will be `5` and not `3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(B2:F6),
     b,TOCOL(IFNA(A2:A6,SEQUENCE(,ROWS(B2:F6)))),
     c,TOCOL(IFNA(B1:F1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:F6)))),
     d,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(a,b,c),1,-1),3),
     VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColID"},
     HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),d)))
```

---

This is another alternative formula but the number of bytes is more as well it uses <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>BYROW( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A1:F6,
     b,TAKE(SORT(TOCOL(DROP(a,1,1)),,-1),3),
     c,BYROW(b,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(REPT(DROP(a,1,-5)&"|"&TAKE(a,1,-5),m=DROP(a,1,1))))),
     d,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(b)),b,TEXTBEFORE(c,"|"),TEXTAFTER(c,"|"))+0,
     VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColID"},d))
```

---

Bit less bytes than the earlier one:

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A6,
     b,B1:F1,
     c,B2:F6,
     d,TAKE(SORT(TOCOL(c),,-1),3),
     e,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Rank",e),REDUCE({"Value","RowID","ColID"},d,LAMBDA(x,y,
     VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,CONCAT(REPT(a,y=c)),CONCAT(REPT(b,y=c)))+0)))))
```

Comment: In this case how can we exclude the diagonal elements?

Comment: @vp_050 have you posted a question for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColID"},HSTACK({1;2;3},TAKE(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(B2:F6&"|"&A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1),"|",{1,2,3}),"|"),,-1),3)))
```

Comment: If any of the cells are blank or there are NAs, how can we ignore these cells in the above formula?