# Ignore blank cells or NAs in a matrix while using SORT function in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have the following matrix with 20 cells each containing an integer value with blank diagonal cells. I wanted to find the top 3 values in the matrix using the SORT function.

The formula used is

```
=VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColID"},HSTACK({1;2;3},TAKE(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(B2:F6&"|"&A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1),"|",{1,2,3}),"|"),,-1),3)))
```

Source:
[Find the corresponding row ID and column ID of top 3 values in a matrix in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871321/find-the-corresponding-row-id-and-column-id-of-top-3-values-in-a-matrix-in-excel)

However, this formula doesn't work with blank cells or cells with NAs. How can I ignore blank cells or cells with NAs when implementing the above formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correction which you needed to the formula you have posted is with an <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> & <kbd>ISNUMBER( )</kbd>:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H6</kbd>

```
=VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColID"},
 HSTACK({1;2;3},TAKE(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&
 TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(B2:F6),B2:F6&"|"&A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1),3),"|", 
 {1,2,3}),"|"),,-1),3)))
```

---

or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     x,ISNUMBER(B2:F6),
     a,TOCOL(IFS(x,B2:F6),3),
     b,TOCOL(IFS(x,A2:A6),3),
     c,TOCOL(IFS(x,B1:F1),3),
     d,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(a,b,c),1,-1),3),
     VSTACK({"Rank","Value","RowID","ColumnID"},
     HSTACK({1;2;3},d)))
```

---

A screenshot showing both formulas work, with tiny adjustments:

[image]

---